# What function or method does pry use when you just pass it an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, irb, pry

I've loaded up `pry` and am debugging some objects. Often times if I just type the name of the object `pry` will output a representation of it on it's own and it looks great.

#### Example:

For example, it's like being at the `pry` prompt and doing something like:

```
[1] pry(main):1> @myobj
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Confusion:

- I didn't call `pp @myobj` or `y @myobj` or `ap @myobj` or `@myobj.inspect`
- If I do call any of those I get output that looks different ( and not as beautifully formatted )

#### Questions:

- What method is being called to output objects this way?
- Can I use that method in a script file to output the format using the same nice formatting?
  ( i.e. doing `pry` and then running `load /path/to/my/file.rb` ? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pry is a REPL - Read Evaluate Print Loop.  If you dig through their source code, you'll see the Print part is ultimately handled by a Proc which, by default, calls the `pp` class method on [`Pry::ColorPrinter`](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/dd2d9b927b0afbe4e5463ff1558c566abbdb0473/lib/pry/color_printer.rb).  That class inherits from `::PP` which is the class responsible for the output in `pp`, it just does some extra stuff pertaining to colours, pagination, etc.  So for the most part, yes, it's just `pp`.

Here's basically a copy-paste of their code which could give you what you want:

```
require 'pp'
require 'coderay'

class MyPrinter < ::PP
  OBJ_COLOR = begin
    code = CodeRay::Encoders::Terminal::TOKEN_COLORS[:keyword]
    if code.start_with? "\e"
      code
    else
      "\e[0m\e[0;#{code}m"
    end
  end

  CodeRay::Encoders::Terminal::TOKEN_COLORS[:comment][:self] = "\e[1;34m"

  def self.pp(obj, out = $>, width = 79)
    q = new(out, width)
    q.guard_inspect_key { q.pp obj }
    q.flush
    out << "\n"
  end

  def text(str, width = str.length)
    if str.include?("\e[")
      super "#{str}\e[0m", width
    elsif str.start_with?('#<') || str == '=' || str == '>'
      super highlight_object_literal(str), width
    else
      super CodeRay.scan(str, :ruby).term, width
    end
  end

  def pp(obj)
    super
  end
end
```

You can tweak it to your liking.  You would then use it by saying something like `MyPrinter.pp(@myobj)`.

If you're not worried about tweaking it and are happy to have a dependency on `Pry` (and all its dependencies), you don't need the above code and can simply use `Pry::ColorPrinter.pp(@myobj)` in your code (making sure to require `pp`, `coderay`, and `pry/color_printer`)

Comment: Also looks like it is possible to do `Pry::ColorPrinter::pp(@myobj)` to get what I wanted ;) but I wouldn't have got this without your help.